# Indra's Mangekyo Sharingan

Tags: naruto

In the manga, Indra is shown with his Mangekyo Sharingan:

[image]

But in the anime, his eyes are like:

[image]

Which one is his actual Mangekyo Sharingan? If it is the one in the anime, then he has the same Mangekyo Sharingan as Sasuke. Then is it true that all Uchihas have unique Mangekyo Sharingans?

Comment: Well i don't know much of the manga but in picture 2 that is his eternal mangekyo sharingan and in picture one i think it's the sharingan but not sure :/

Comment: Could you please provide the manga chapter from which the first picture has been taken from?

Comment: @YOURWORSTNIGHTMARE Indra didn't require the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, as he inherited the body and eyes of the Sage. Also, who would he take it from? He battled Asura and Senju for years being able to use Susano'o the entire time. He didn't need EMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anime episode showing Indra having Sasuke's eyes is a filler episode ([see the list here](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden)). Trust the manga instead, which is canon. There are two reasons why the producers did changed it in the anime:

1. They got lazy, or they didn't have enough time to think of a unique mangekyo sharingan ability and animate the effects. So they slapped Sasuke's eyes onto Indra and called it a day.
2. Indra having Sasuke's eyes symbolizes how Sasuke is the reincarnation of Indra. Indra's personality, physical prowess, and intelligence were all passed down to him. So it makes sense that the MS was also passed down too.

Comment: Indra did have Sharingan, did you not see the picture on top?

Comment: You can find his MS here: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan

Comment: I think the second reason is accurate. Thanks!

Comment: I personally don't like the second reason though, cuz then why does itachi get amaterasu? and what about madara, another indra reincarnate, does he get it?

Comment: The second reason doesn't make any sense. Madara was also a reincarnation of Indra. So why does his MS look different?

Comment: Dunno. Go for the first reason then.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the will definitely be a few differences between the anime itself and the manga, for example, in the anime "one piece" there is a character named "Zoro," but in the manga, his name is "Solo." See the difference. Basically it really is for you to decide.

Comment: that would be in the English DUB only. In the Subbed versions, they use the actual names, but due to Japaneese pronunciation, the names sound different. the Main character of One piece, Luffy, for instance, is pronounced Ruffy, Because L sounds are difficult for japaneese speakers to pronounce, or something like that. The dubs took the pronunciation as the name, rather than the actual written name. The Op is talking about FIller episodes, which are a whole other story, better explained by Jerffery Tangs answer.

Answer (score 0):

no. It says that all UCHIHA have different Mangekyou Sharingan. But Indra is an Otsutsuki, so that means that it must be different

Comment: Indra is technically the first Uchiha.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because it's a filler arc and they didn't want to have to design a new pattern. It makes no sense for his to be the same as Sasuke's. Madara is also Indra's reincarnation, yet his pattern is different. Also, Sasuke doesn't awaken the mangekyou sharingan until after Obito implants Itachi's eyes in him, so Sasuke's sharingan isn't even really his own, and that means the theory that it's because he's Indra's reincarnation doesn't have any credence.