# What Sharingan does Indra have?

Tags: naruto

Does Indra have the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan  or the normal Mangekyo Sharingan? I don't know if he has the EMS or the MS because he is the first Uchiha.

Comment: Related: [Indra's Mangekyo Sharingan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40175/indras-mangekyo-sharingan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indra has MS, a strong MS at that. What you're having confused is that Sasuke's EMS and Indra's MS look the same, because after awakening his EMS, Sasuke was able to use Indra's chakra (being his reincarnate).